# Removing an uploaded and unreferenced image

Tags: support, images, imgur

NOTE: I saw a couple similar questions, but I didn't see the answer I was looking for.

I was uploading images to question I had in a Stack Exchange community, and one of them I uploaded without cropping out a part I didn't want. For Personal/Privacy reasons I want it removed. I fixed the image and the question I made now has the fixed image, however the one with privacy concern was still uploaded on the `stack.imgur`, and I'd like it removed.

I've sent a couple requests to imgur, and one support form to the Stack Exchange community in questions support.

Will the image be removed for good? I have not referenced the link on any webpage. What are the chances of it appearing in Google searches?

Comment: Was it for [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/791705/strange-visual-artifacts-windows-7)? Then your original image URL is now lost in the mists of the internet, and you don't need to worry, really.

Comment: The Second image (Bottom One) had a privacy concern of mine.  Yes it was that post.

Comment: Sorry, I worded it bad, the second image is the fixed version of the original that had the privacy concern. the Post is fine now, however I'm concerned about the original being uploaded.

Comment: Then you replaced the image URL during the grace period; as there are 62^5 different URL name combinations (916.132.832, so close to 1 billion), no one is ever going to find that image now.

Comment: What do you mean by I replaced the image URL in the grace period? I have 4 URLs associated with that post. 1, the first image which is fine, 2 the second image which was fixed and is now fine, 3, I had uploaded the second (fixed image) twice because I accidently deleted the URLs text and I couldn't remember it, and 4. the the image which had the privacy concern. All 4 images have unique URLs and were uploaded, 2 are used, 1 is useless, and 1 has the privacy issue.

Comment: Yes, but your post *no longer contains the URL*. Nor does the revision history of the post contain the URL anymore. Only you may still know that URL, as *no other page on the internet links to it anymore*.

Answer (score 4):

Images uploaded to `i.stack.imgur.com` are never removed.

However, if your post is no longer using them, then they won't be indexed either. Old revisions of posts are not indexed by Google or other search engines. Because the image urls are random string combinations, there is little chance of anyone else stumbling on to them either.

If you managed to replace the image in the grace period (the first 5 minutes of posting) then there is not even a revision containing the image URL and noone will find it, really.

If you are really concerned, it may be that the Stack Exchange team can delete images from `i.stack.imgur.com`. Try the [*Contact Us*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form, explain what the image URL is and why you want it removed.

Comment: I have sent a support email to the contact us of the stack exchange community in question. How long will it take?

Comment: @Keyes: I don't know. That depends on Stack Exchange staff availability and how much other email they have to handle.

Comment: @Keyes if you don't get any response from SE team in email after two days, you can try in chat, there's usually at least one Community Manager around in the Tavern. Despite its fun side, it's also used for serious things when you need the team's attention.

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look into it. If imgur themselvea dont respond after tommorrow or SE, ill go to the chat. The privacy/security concern wont kill me, but its information nobody should see or need to other than me, and id be concerned if anyone could see it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard unfortunately I cannot use the chat due to low reputation so im kind of stuck. No replies from SE.

Comment: @Keyes now you can. (give it few minutes if you can't right now)